# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0-rc4 UploadFileFilter doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I need to add upload file for `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0-rc4`. In earlier version it works like:

```
public class SwaggerUploadFileParametersFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters != null)
        {
            var attribute =
                apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<UploadFileParametersAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                operation.consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");
                operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
                {
                    name = "file",
                    required = true,
                    type = "file",
                    @in = "formData"
                }
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

[UploadFileParameters]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> MyMethod([FromUri]MyMethodParams parameters)
```

I try to implement it using `Microsoft.OpenApi.Models` objects:

```
   public class SwaggerUploadFileParametersFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var actionAttributes = context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes<UploadFileParametersAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (actionAttributes != null)
            {
                operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody()
                {
                    Content =
                    {
                        ["multipart/form-data"] = new OpenApiMediaType()
                        {
                            Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
                            {
                                Properties =
                                {
                                    ["file"] = new OpenApiSchema()
                                    {
                                        Description = "Select file",
                                        Type = "file"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I don't see file component in swagger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code and some documentation from [Swagger File Upload](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/)

I modified your code and added small fix

```cs
public class SwaggerUploadFileParametersFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var parameters = operation.Parameters;
        if (parameters == null || parameters.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var isUploadFile = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.Any(x => x.ParameterType == typeof(IFormFile));

        if (isUploadFile)
        {
            operation.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody()
            {
                Content =
                {
                    ["multipart/form-data"] = new OpenApiMediaType()
                    {
                        Schema = new OpenApiSchema()
                        {
                            Type = "object",
                            Properties =
                            {
                                ["file"] = new OpenApiSchema()
                                {
                                    Description = "Select file", Type = "string", Format = "binary"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesDefaultResponseType]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileAsync([FromForm] IFormFile file)
```

Comment: I have tried this and on the swagger UI the choose file dialog window has disappeared; this is hugely confusing from the Pre-OpenAPI changes. That was infinitely simpler and easier to follow and implement.

Comment: Secondly when debugging, the `IFormFile` file parameter is not detected when passed into the OperationFilter. The `operation.Parameters` collection is empty.

Comment: I think swagger didnt find your controller on scanning, because im using same implementation, maybe the action param name its not corresponding with ["file"] name